# To combine data using gawk

Tags: shell-script

here my data :
Examples :

> 454|12 13 |Peoples Telephone (China Mobile Hong Kong)|0.0118
>   454|06 15 17 |SmarTone Mobile Comms (P Plus)|0.0412

im quite new unix/linux. May i know is there any command so i can populate data as below:

> 45412 |Peoples Telephone (China Mobile Hong Kong)|0.0118
>   45413 |Peoples Telephone (China Mobile Hong Kong)|0.0118
>   45406 |SmarTone Mobile Comms (P Plus)|0.0412
>   45415 |SmarTone Mobile Comms (P Plus)|0.0412
>   45417 |SmarTone Mobile Comms (P Plus)|0.0412

I using gawk command to print the first part

> ( gawk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}{print $1}'

but failed to combine with each breakout. Need your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gawk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}{n=split($2,a," "); for (i = 1; i <=n ; i++) printf "%s%s|%s|%s\n", $1,a[i],$3,$4;}'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works like charm. I just need to sort data now. :)

Comment: Ohh okay..already done :D